# php: session disappears after page navigation

Tags: php, session

I've read all the posts I could find about this issue, but, to date, none of the solutions have worked for me. Obviously, I'm overlooking something important. I also don't know how to debug sessions. I read one article, [PHP session Debugging](http://css.dzone.com/news/php-session-debugging), but it was over my head.

So, much like the other issues, when I navigate to another page in my app, whether through a link or a form submit, my session disappears. I have no idea why my session vanishes. If someone has the time to help me investigate, it would be greatly appreciated.

These are my php.ini settings

```
; Name of the session (used as cookie name).  
session.name = PHPSESSID  

; The path for which the cookie is valid.  
session.cookie_path = /
```

This is the first view to display

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['session_id'])) {
    $_SESSION['session_id'] = session_id();
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['invoices'])) {
    $_SESSION['invoices'] = $invoices;
}

if (isset($_SESSION['session_id'])) {
    print_r($_SESSION['session_id'] . " in invoiceList.<br />");
} else {
    echo 'No session ID set in invoiceList <br />';
}
?>
<div>

    <table>
        <tr>            
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Invoice Date</th>
            <th>Invoice Number</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php
            include_once 'form/editInvoice.php';
            if (isset($invoices)) {

                foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
                    ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $invoice['customer_name'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $invoice['invoice_date'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $invoice['invoice_number'] ?></td>
                    <td><a href='<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>/retrieve?class=InvoiceLineItems&amp;id=<?php echo $invoice['invoice_id']; ?>'><?php echo $invoice['invoice_id']; ?></a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        } else {
            echo 'No invoices retrieved.';
        }
        ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the included form:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['session_id'])) {
    print_r($_SESSION['session_id'] . "in editForm<br />");
} else {
    echo 'No session ID set in editForm <br />';
}

if (!$_POST) {
    ?>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Enter Updated PO Number</legend>
            <li>PO Number: <input type="text" name="po_number"/></li>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="button" onclick="alert('Changes Canceled.')" value="Cancel"/>
    </form>
<?php }
?>
```

And finally, the detail page for when the user clicks a link in the main page.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['session_id'])) {
    print_r($_SESSION['session_id'] . "<br />");
} else {
    echo 'No session ID set invoice<br />';
}
?>

<h1>Invoice Detail</h1>
<div>
<?php
foreach ($partnerInfo as $info) {

    switch ($info['role_indicator']) {
        case 'remit_to':
            ?>
            <div id="remit">
                <ul>
                    <li>PLEASE REMIT TO:</li>
                    <li><?php echo $info['partner_name']; ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo $info['street_name']; ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo $info['city_name']; ?>, <?php echo $info['state']; ?> <?php echo $info['postal_code']; ?></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <?php break; ?>
        <?php case 'seller': ?>
            <div id = "seller" >
                <ul>
                    <li>Service Site:</li>
                    <li><?php echo $info['partner_name']; ?></li>
                    <?php
                    if ($info['partner_aux_info'] !== NULL) {
                        ?><li><?php echo $info['partner_aux_info']; ?>
                        <?php }
                        ?>
                    </li>
                    <li><?php echo $info['street_name']; ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo $info['city_name']; ?>, <?php echo $info['state']; ?> <?php echo $info['postal_code']; ?></li>
                    <li>(405)677-0221</li>
                </ul>        
            </div>
            <?php break; ?>
        <?php case 'sold_to': ?>
            <div id="buyer">
                <ul>
                    <li>Bill To: </li>
                    <li><?php echo $info['partner_name']; ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo $info['street_name']; ?></li>
                    <?php
                    if ($info['suite_info'] !== NULL) {
                        ?><li><?php echo $info['suite_info']; ?>
                        <?php }
                        ?>
                    </li>
                    <li><?php echo $info['city_name']; ?>, <?php echo $info['state']; ?> <?php echo $info['postal_code']; ?></li>
                </ul> 
            </div>   
            <?php break; ?>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
<h1>Line Items</h1>
<table>
    <th>PO Number</th>
    <th>PO Issued Date</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Service Start Date</th>
    <th>Service End Date</th>
    <th>Shipped Date</th>

    <?php foreach ($invoiceLineItems as $lineItem) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $lineItem['po_number']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $lineItem['po_issued_date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $lineItem['line_item_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $lineItem['service_period_start']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $lineItem['service_period_end']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $lineItem['request_for_delivery']; ?></td>
        </tr>       
        <?php
    }
    ?>

</table>


</div>
```

Edit: I've removed the session checks and updated the code sample. I've added session_start() before my `<head>` tag in index.php. I've verified that I can write to the session temp folder.

When i execute this code in my controller to update the invoices with the new PO number, I reach the model's function, but the session is gone.

```
//If form is posted, update line items with PO number and date.
if (isset($_POST['po_number'])) {
    $this->invoice->update();
}
```

By the time I reach the session variable assignment, I have no session data:

public function update() {

```
$con = $this->_getLocalConn();


$invoices = $_SESSION['invoices'];

try {
    $sqlUpdate = $con->prepare("UPDATE invoices 
                                SET po_number = ?, po_issued_date = ?
                                WHERE invoice_id = ?");

    foreach ($invoices as $record) {
        $sqlUpdate->execute(array(
            $_POST['po_number'],
            getdate(),
            $record['invoice_id']
        ));
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
}
//get the PO number being used to update the records
//perform db update where po_number = input
//notify user of success and display updated records.
```

}

Comment: You can simplify all your session handling to just: `session_start()` at the start of your script *before* headers are sent.  The rest is handled for you by default.

Comment: No `$_SESSION` is started to being with when you check it with your first `if`. You **must** call `session_start()` PRIOR to doing anything with a `$_SESSION`!

Comment: @PenguinCoder i added the error check because i didn't know how else to track it.

Comment: @Daren So if I add session_start() in my index.php view, does that infer my session is active throughout the app? I'm new to session usage. So I don't know what to look for when things don't work.

Comment: The session will be started/created when you first call `session_start()`. That makes it available for *this* invocation of the script. Using cookie_path of `/` means use the same session for the entire site. So if you had a separate page of `blah.php` and had `session_start()` in there as well, you would get back the same session as `index.php`. Each execution to access the session information has to call `session_start()`.

Comment: You only need call `session_start()` once per execution.  Put it at the top of your `index.php` and remove it from all the includes.  You don't need it there.

Comment: I removed `session_start` from all but the index page. When I submit the form, I get an empty session. I don't know where the session data went. Am I assuming incorrectly that once the session restarts, the data will get loaded with it or is there something I need to do to fetch it from the cookie?

Comment: I never made any progress on this issue. Since the last comment, I have figured out how to use sessions (a little). Everyone who helped said basically the same thing. So I'll accept the first answer so you get credit for it. At least the sessions aren't disappearing now. Thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each PHP file should start with `session_start();` regardless of `$_SESSION` being set or not. This function will create a new session OR take up the existing one.

Comment: each file or each view page? as an added note, i checked the temp directory and all my sessions were written out. so i know i have write access to that folder.

Comment: I removed the session check. I only had it because I was trying to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

All of your code that needs the session information should start with `session_start()`.  `session_start()` needs to happen before any headers or other output would be written.
Setup and teardown are then handled for you.

I do this:

```
session_start();
$s = &$_SESSION;
```

Then you can use read/write `$s` just like it was `$_SESSION`

If you are doing self referencing image downloads or other code that may end up wanting to execute in parallel, NOT starting a session or closing it as soon as possible with `session_write_close()` will give you a significant performance boost.
Without this, sessions essentially make your code run single threaded.

Edit: Saying single threaded was perhaps a bad choice of words. 
Lets say you had a page with three iframes in it, each one loading a different (or the same) php script.  If you are using sessions, the result would be the iframes loading one at a time instead of all at once.  Each one would get a lock on the session and the others would wait at `session_start()` until the session was available again.

Comment: I'm not trying to build a multi-threaded app, but thanks for the note. All I want to do is save on multiple db calls because I'll use the same data in different places.

Answer (score 1):

No `$_SESSION` is started to begin with when you check it with your first `if`. Therefore, it will always FAIL. You must call `session_start()` PRIOR to doing anything with a `$_SESSION` variable. Correct your code.

First page:

```
<?php
session_start();

/* Don't need this unless you really need the debugging
   Previously you where assigning variables that did not 
   exist to the the $_SESSION variables. Not what you want
   I imagine.

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    var_dump($_SESSION);

}
*/
...
```

Include form:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['session_id'])) {
    print_r($_SESSION['session_id'] . "in editForm<br />");
} else {
    echo 'No session ID set in editForm <br />';
}
...
```

Detail page:

```
<?php
session_start(); //Notice a pattern here??


if (isset($_SESSION['session_id'])) {
    print_r($_SESSION['session_id'] . "<br />");
} else {
    echo 'No session ID set invoice<br />';
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm incorporating all the suggestions. I greatly appreciate the help from everyone. See my edit for an update. Thanks.